# Attempting to edit array that contains specific key

Tags: lua

So I am trying to edit my config list where it has to edit robbed to true when entity is equal to entity in the list (entities get generated when my script is starting)

```lua
Config file

Config.location = {
    [1] = {
        x = 24.39,
        y = -1345.776,
        z = 29.49,
        h = 267.58,
        robbed = false,
        entity = nil
    },
    [2] = {
        x = -47.7546,
        y = -1759.276,
        z = 29.421,
        h = 48.035,
        robbed = false,
        entity = nil
    },
}
```

So this list gets loaded - When [1] has been robbed it should change robbed in [1] if the entity matches.

I would imagine i should do a for loop but i'm still clueless.

Comment: You should know that `[1] = ` is completely redundant. `{{}, {}}` is an array of two tables, with indices 1 and 2.

Comment: Do you have an example of an attempt to make a change to `Config.location[1].robbed`?

Comment: Well so far i am heading this way with the code

https://gyazo.com/2221623d7674892ae7e0ec68bfb9080f

Comment: don't post code as linked images... edit your question!

Comment: You have a little typo in line 6, `locations` instead of `location`.

Answer (score 1):

As Config.list is a sequence with positive integer keys starting from 1 you can conveniently use the [iparis](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-ipairs) iterator in combination with a [generic for loop](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.5) to check every entry in your list.

```
for i,v in ipairs(Config.location) do
  v.robbed = v.entity == someOtherEntity and true or false
end
```

Of course your entity entries shouldn't be nil as this wouldn't make sense.